I couldn't copy and paste these line of codes in my overleaf
$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$As you have discovered, the chain rule can be difficult to apply in Matrix Calculus because it involves higher-order tensors (i.e. matrix-by-vector, vector-by-matrix, and matrix-by-matrix gradients) which are difficult to calculate, awkward to manipulate, and don't fit into standard matrix notation.

Instead I would recommend a differential approach, because the differential of a matrix behaves like a matrix. In particular, it can be written using standard matrix notation and it obeys all of the rules of matrix algebra. 

Also, the $\c{\rm Frobenius}$ product is extraordinarily useful in Matrix Calculus
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \qquad \big\{{\rm \c{Frobenius}\;norm}\big\}\\
}$$
The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in such a
product to be rearranged in many equivalent ways, e.g. 
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A \;=\; \LR{A^TC}:B \\\\
}$$


---


Using the above notation, the manipulation of your particular function becomes almost mechanical
$$\eqalign{
df &= \gradLR fZ:dZ \\
   &= \gradLR fZ:\LR{dX^TY} \\
   &= \gradLR fZ Y^T:dX^T \\
   &= Y\gradLR fZ^T:dX \\
\grad fX &= Y\gradLR fZ^T \\
}$$
Note that there was no need for a tensor-valued gradient in any step, just plain old matrices.

Also note that your initial dimension-matching approach was correct! That's not as crazy an idea as it seems. When dealing with *rectangular* matrices there is often only one way to fit all the pieces together and it's a useful shortcut. But it won't help when dealing with *square* matrices.

The above is from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4617988/matrix-derivative-of-fxt-y-w-r-t-x/4618182#4618182.
It fails in my overleaf due to \eqalign.

The quick answer is that Math.SE is using MathJax, not TeX.  To translate to LaTeX, you'll need to use the appropriate packages.  It's hard to tell here because you're code isn't formatted, but I would guess you want to \usepackage{amsmath} and then change eqalign to align.

@Teepeemm I tried that. But that doesn't work.

"doesn't work" is not a useful description, show a small complete document and show the error rthat you get

\eqalign  is not defined in latex.

@DavidCarlisle Oops. So what is an easy way to fix this?

all the definitions \def\o{{\tt1}}... are inside a $...$ group so they will become undefined at the second $

in latex you can not use \equalign and you should not use \def, \c, \rmor$$` and as noted above the definitions should not be made inside a math group.

$$\eqalign{ should be \begin{align} and }$$ should be \end{align}  for example.

You need to use LaTeX markup, so something like

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}
\DeclareMathOperator\trace{trace}
\begin{document}


As you have discovered, the chain rule can be difficult to apply in
Matrix Calculus because it involves higher-order tensors
(i.e. matrix-by-vector, vector-by-matrix, and matrix-by-matrix
gradients) which are difficult to calculate, awkward to manipulate,
and don't fit into standard matrix notation.

Instead I would recommend a differential approach, because the
differential of a matrix behaves like a matrix. In particular, it can
be written using standard matrix notation and it obeys all of the
rules of matrix algebra.

Also, the \textcolor{red}{Frobenius} product is extraordinarily useful in Matrix Calculus
\begin{align}
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \qquad \bigl\{\text{\textcolor{red}{Frobenius} norm}\bigr\}
\end{align}
The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in such a
product to be rearranged in many equivalent ways, e.g. 
\begin{align}
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:(AB) &= (CB^T):A \;=\; (A^TC):B 
\end{align}

\end{document}

